UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `<bucket-name>.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com' at port `undefined'. This service may not be available in the region
I am uploading files to AWS S3 bucket using AWS SDK. The code was working fine but suddenly i started getting the following error:

UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: <bucket-name>.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com' at port undefined'. This service may not be available in the `ap-south-1' region.

I tried uploading files through AWS CLI and it is working.

I just tried pinging that host name and it worked for me. Can you try again, or try on a different network (eg home vs office vs tethered via your phone)?

@JohnRotenstein  I pinged the hostname and now it started uploading. I am not able to figure out what was the issue. Can you explain?

sometimes there is regional outgae, i had amplify outage once and s3 outage twice this month

But file was getting uploaded through AWS CLI

It would be awesome if you can replicate the sceneario
